# Where to find configuration parameters for pandas-profiling?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I am having a difficult time finding the default configuration parameters (the `kwargs` argument) used in `df.profile_report` and `pandas_profiling.ProfileReport`. Where can I find a list of what parameters are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, the key-value store for those arguments is here: https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/blob/master/src/pandas_profiling/config_default.yaml

An example of how you might use them:

```py
report = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(
    df,
    check_recoded=False,
    check_correlation_pearson=False,
    check_correlation_cramers=False,
    missing_diagrams={
        'bar': False,
        'matrix': False,
        'heatmap': False,
        'dendrogram': False
    }
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the link above is 404.